# Print Register in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, printing, x86

Followed a couple of online documents and yet when I try to print the number I have stored in the register %ecx nothing happens. Could this be because I'm essentially performing calculations and then trying to print while in a loop?

```
   mov     $48, %ecx  #Convert to ascii
   mov     $1, %edx   #Print Byte
   add     %eax, %ecx

   mov     $4, %eax          #Output To Console
   mov     $1, %ebx          #File Descriptor - Standardout
   int      $0x80            #Call the Kernel
```

Answer (score 5):

The `write` system call expects a pointer to the data to be printed. As far as I can tell, you have a single digit. You can temporarily store that on the stack for printing as follows:

```
mov     $48, %ecx  #Convert to ascii
mov     $1, %edx   #Print Byte
add     %eax, %ecx
push    %ecx       # store on stack
mov     %esp, %ecx # load address
mov     $4, %eax   # Output To Console
mov     $1, %ebx   # File Descriptor - Standardout
int     $0x80      # Call the Kernel
pop     %ecx       # clean up stack
```

Remember that you will need a better conversion routine for multi-digit numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This systemcall is a `write`. In C the siganture would be:

```
int write(int fd[ebx], char *p[ecx], int size[edx]);
```

Now looking at your code, `ebx`, `edx` and `eax` is ok. But `ecx` is a pointer to a buffer, not a character. Furthermore I don't really know what

```
add eax, ecx
```

is supposed to do, as `eax` is not defined in your snippet.

So what you have to do is, reserve a buffer in memory, put the byte(s) you want to write into it, and the let `ecx` point to it.

If `eax` is supposed to be a single digit in the range `0-9` then it would be more readable if you put `mov $'0', ecx`.

Comment: The `$` sign in the gnu assembler means `immediate`, not hexadecimal. So `$48` was correct. Of course `$'0'` would be even more readable.

Comment: OK. I don't really know the AT&T syntax, and from M68000 (as example) the $ would denote a hex number (other assemblers as well). :) Thx for the update.