# Why I can't output number from stack. The first I pop ebp and I want to output in console. But my code doesn't work

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data

section .bss
x2 resb 4

section .text
global _start

_start:
mov ecx, 5
mov eax, 6
push ecx
push eax

pop ebp

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, ebp
mov edx, 15
int 80h

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question in lacking in details. What doesn't work with your code? [Edit] the question to include enough details that we can provide an answer. See [ask].

Comment: Please re-read the documentation for the `int 80h/eax=4` system call.

Comment: AT&T duplicate of the same question: [Print Register in Assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22621780)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **print a number** on console standard output in human-readable format, you need to convert it to this format first. It doesn't matter where you've got the number from: a memory variable, stack or from an immediate value loaded to a register, as it is in your example:

```
mov eax, 6
push eax
pop ebp       
mov ecx, ebp
```

Kernel service [sys_write](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man2/write.2.html) expects that the second argument ***buf** is a pointer to memory variable (buffer). It is provided to `int 80h` in register `ecx`; in your case you loaded this register with `00000006h`. When kernel tries to read `edx=15` bytes from this address, this will fail because such low address is not available for your program.

Reserve a buffer for the decimal digits, e.g. `Decimal resb 12`, [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894) your number to this buffer and load its address by `lea ecx,[Decimal]` before using the service `int 80h/eax=4`.